# Read n rows from an h5 file

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read only 10 **rows** from an h5 file:

```
df = pd.read_hdf('data.h5', 'cleanuserbase', start=0, stop=10)
```

But that doesn't work because it reads all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

This works only if your object is table format (rather than [fixed format](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#fixed-format)).

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2))

In [12]: store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')

In [13]: df.to_hdf("store.h5", "df", format="table")

In [14]: store.select("df", "index < 2")
Out[14]:
          0         1
0 -0.245982 -1.047534
1 -0.633943 -1.218812

In [15]: pd.read_hdf("store.h5", "df", start=0, stop=2)  # works if non-integer index
Out[15]:
          0         1
0 -0.245982 -1.047534
1 -0.633943 -1.218812
```

*See [table format](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#table-format) in the docs.*

---

If your table is fixed format it can only be read in whole (but perhaps [this should raise](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8287)):

```
In [21]: df.to_hdf("store.h5", "fixed_df", format="fixed")

In [22]: pd.read_hdf("store.h5", "fixed_df", start=0, stop=2)
Out[22]:
           0         1
0   2.532604 -0.084852
1   0.735833 -1.100600
2  -0.415245 -2.050627
3  -0.915045 -0.638667
...  # and all the other rows
```

Comment: The indexes in my file aren't known.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp this works (start and stop) with non-integer index.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Do start and stop not work for you with format=table? Are you using a recent version of pandas?

Answer (score 1):

This is not implemented for `fixed` stores ATM (but works for `table` stores, see Andy's answer), see the open issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8287)

That said, the stores themselves do actually support indexing. Its just not built out. This is peeking into the internals.

```
In [35]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2),columns=list('ab'))

In [36]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5',mode='w')

In [37]: store.put('df',df)

In [38]: store
Out[38]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
/df            frame        (shape->[10,2])

In [39]: mask = slice(4,10)

In [40]: s = store.get_storer('df').storable

In [41]: DataFrame(s.block0_values[mask],index=s.axis1[mask],columns=s.axis0)
Out[41]: 
axis0         a         b
4     -1.347325 -0.936605
5     -0.342814 -0.452055
6      0.951228  0.160918
7     -0.096133  0.816032
8     -0.731431  1.190047
9     -1.050826  0.348107

In [42]: store.close()
```

I suppose this could raise `NotImplementedError` until this issue is resolved.